# Style last item differently with Isotope jQuery script

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a site that has a product info laid out in a CSS grid where the last div of each row has to be a member of the .last css class. I'd like to use Isotope to handle the sorting and filtering effects, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get elements rearranged by Isotope at the end of each row to get assigned the .last class so that they don't overflow into the space that the next row is using.

How can I use Isotope while ensuring that the last div of each row retains the .last class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Targeting first item after sorting - Metafizzy blog](http://metafizzy.co/blog/targeting-sorting-items)

Comment: Even though you are the author of said plugin, please add the relevant information here instead if just linking to another page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer (Provide context for links).